# CodeIgniter Message System

Tags: codeigniter

I'm finding for a message passing system for codeIgniter. I found 3 ways.

1) set_flashdata(); from session class,
2) form_validaion from form validation class and
3) a variable set in controller and show it in view file.

1) is good, but we can only use for next server request. we can't use it for calling views.
2) can only use for form validation and it doesn't disappear on page refreshs.
3) is also doesn't disappear on page refreshs and we had to set it manually for form validation errors.

my want is like set_flashdata, show only one time and disappear on page refresh, doesn't need to set error message manually for form validations and able to use together with calling views.

It is not so bad if we use all three ways together, but I hope for better way.
Is there any ways or something for it? 
Thanks!

Comment: What did you figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to directly display flashdata in the view? Normally you just pass the flashdata to the view via the controller. I wouldn't recommend any other way.

Controller:

```
$data['var'] = $this->session->flashdata('var');
$this->load->view('view_file', $data);
```

View:

```
This is the flashdata: <?php echo $var; ?>
```